# How to avoid conditional statements using polymorphism?

Tags: php, oop, conditional-statements, polymorphism, abstract-class

Product class is the abstract class and three child classes extends to it. createProduct method is in the ProductController class, it is a common method to save the data in the database.

```
class PenDrive extends Product
{
    public function constructorWithArguments5($ID, $name, $price, $productType, $size)
    {
        parent::__construct($ID, $name, $price, $productType);
        $this->size= $size;
    }
    public function setProduct()
{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO product (ID, productName, price, productType, weight) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)  ";
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute([$this->getID(), $this->getName(), $this->getPrice(), $this->getProductType(), $this->size]);

        $_SESSION['save-btn'] = "Products added succesfully";
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }


}
```

Below is another child class

```
class Luggage extends Product
{
public function constructorWithArguments7($ID, $name, $price, $productType, $height, $width, $length) {
        parent::__construct($ID, $name, $price, $productType);
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->length = $length;
    }
public function setProduct()
    {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO product (ID, productName, price, productType, height, width, length) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ";
            $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute([$this->getID(), $this->getName(), $this->getPrice(), $this->getProductType(), $this->height, $this->width, $this->length]);

            $_SESSION['save-btn'] = "Products added succesfully";
            header("Location:../index.php");
}
}
```

Below is the controller class

```
class ProductController
{
    public function createProduct($ID, $name, $price, $productType, $capacity, $height, $width, $length, $size)
    {
 if ($productType === 'Bottle') {
            $Bottle= new Bottle($ID, $name, $price, $productType, $capacity);
            $Bottle->setProduct();
        }
        elseif ($productType === 'Luggage ') {
            $Luggage = new Luggage ($ID, $name, $price, $productType, $height, $width, $length);
            $Luggage ->setProduct();
        }
        elseif ($productType === 'PenDrive') {
            $PenDrive= new PenDrive($ID, $name, $price, $productType, $size);
            $PenDrive->setProduct();
        }
}
```

The above code is working perfectly. I have to remove the If statements in createProduct() method in the controller class, I have been asked to do it with polymorphism. Please help me to remove the conditional statements with polyorphism.

Comment: You could introduce a factory, I guess, but that'd just be moving the `if` to somewhere else. This is a good candidate for `match`, which is my preference, but that's just a fancy `if` at the end of the day, so I don't know if that qualifies. You can do a [`class_exists`](https://3v4l.org/cVAoY) but I personally think that's pretty hacky, or you could go full reflection, too. But someone needs to turn an arbitrary string into an object, and polymorphism alone isn't going to do it.

Comment: The controller itself is suspect. Presumably you are passing `null` to each argument that you aren't using for a given product type, which implies that the caller "knows" which to set to null and therefore knows what product is being acted upon, so you could instead turn this into multiple controllers which are polymorphic, maybe with only 4 common arguments and an array for the remaining ones, but that's a bit ugly, too. You could also just have multiple routes for each. I hope whoever assigned this to you will give you good feedback if you aren't doing it how they expected.